# Qt serial communication terminal

Tags: c++, qt, terminal, communication

I'm trying to modify `Qt` terminal example. I'm new to `Qt` and I have a problem with `setCentralWidget(console);` Now the console is stretched to whole window. There is only a main toolbar, a status bar, a menu and I would like to add some buttons etc.

I know that I should use layers before setting central widget but I don't know how. I would like to put this console into small text area just to get info from serial. For sending commands buttons will be available.

Can some one help me with changing this code ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-layouts.html) yet? Was there something in particular you didn't quite understand?

Comment: Yes I was trying to implement examples from docs but they are written without gui creator and whatever I do I'm getting compilation errors and I don't know how to get this working. As I wrote I'm new to qt and also c++ this is why I asked for example how to change it telling what I need to achieve.

Comment: You may want to try posting the compiler errors you're seeing, and the code that's relevant. Also, I recommend reading ["How To Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center to improve your chances of getting assistance. It's tough to help with nearly no information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for my problem. It is very simple. First we have to create new layout for example gridlayout, then addWidget to  layout and set central widget from Qwidget as below:

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;

layout->addWidget(ui->tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 2);
layout->addWidget(ui->info, 1, 0, 1, 2);
layout->addWidget(console, 2, 0, 1, 2);

QWidget *window = new QWidget();
window->setLayout(layout);

setCentralWidget(window);
```